# Make a Custom Rally Grid a Bulk-Edit capable grid

Tags: rally

Is it possible to add Bulk-Edit capabilities to a grid in a custom Rally app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there aren't any pre-built hooks that you can toggle to make an AppSDK2 grid bulk-editable. I can see where this would be useful though - I'd recommend posting this as a Feature Request to [Rally Ideas](https://ideas.rallydev.com).

Answer (score 0):

With App SDK v2.0rc3 you can add "enableBulkEdit: true" to the list of grid configs and it will add that capability